# How to match values with dates and create new columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataset that has the parameter, dates, and values in the same column. I am looking for a way to match them and create separate columns. I'm trying to get the **end result to look like the following** for each different parameter:

[image]
**This is the sample dataset:**

```
df<-structure(list(`Date & Time` = c(NA, NA, "Minimum", "MinDate", 
"Maximum", "MaxDate", "Avg", "Num", "Data[%]", "STD"), Bayonne...2 = c("WSPD", 
"mph", "1.1", "1/1/2019 1:00 AM", "22.4", "1/21/2019 7:00 PM", 
"8.3", "743", "99.8", "4.7"), Bayonne...3 = c("WDIR", "Deg", 
"20", "1/5/2019 4:00 PM", "337", "1/27/2019 11:00 PM", "206", 
"743", "99.8", "100.7"), Bayonne...4 = c("TEMP", "DegF", "3", 
"1/31/2019 4:00 AM", "59", "1/24/2019 12:00 PM", "32", "743", 
"99.8", "10"), Bayonne...5 = c("RH", "%", "27", "1/7/2019 6:00 PM", 
"88.2", "1/1/2019 4:00 AM", "55.5", "743", "99.8", "15.1"), Bayonne...6 = c("BP", 
"in HG", "29.21", "1/20/2019 10:00 AM", "30.64", "1/22/2019 9:00 AM", 
"30.04", "743", "99.8", "0.2"), Bayonne...7 = c("RAIN", "in", 
"0", "1/1/2019 2:00 AM", "0.286", "1/24/2019 10:00 AM", "2.946", 
"743", "99.8", "No Data"), `Camden Spruce St...8` = c("WSPD", 
"mph", "0.6", "1/18/2019 1:00 PM", "21.2", "1/10/2019 2:00 PM", 
"6.2", "744", "100", "4.3"), `Camden Spruce St...9` = c("WDIR", 
"Deg", "27", "1/5/2019 9:00 AM", "332", "1/10/2019 8:00 PM", 
"205", "744", "100", "95.5"), `Camden Spruce St...10` = c("TEMP", 
"DegF", "6", "1/31/2019 2:00 AM", "60", "1/1/2019 9:00 AM", "33", 
"744", "100", "10.1"), `Camden Spruce St...11` = c("RH", "%", 
"24.5", "1/12/2019 2:00 PM", "89.3", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "52.9", 
"744", "100", "17.6"), `Camden Spruce St...12` = c("BP", "in HG", 
"29.22", "1/20/2019 9:00 AM", "30.69", "1/22/2019 10:00 AM", 
"30.06", "744", "100", "0.2"), `Camden Spruce St...13` = c("RAIN", 
"in", "0", "1/1/2019 2:00 AM", "0.233", "1/19/2019 11:00 PM", 
"3.249", "744", "100", "No Data"), Columbia...14 = c("WSPD", 
"mph", "0.5", "1/28/2019 6:00 PM", "14", "1/29/2019 11:00 PM", 
"3.5", "743", "99.8", "2.7"), Columbia...15 = c("WDIR", "Deg", 
"69", "1/1/2019 1:00 AM", "341", "1/1/2019 1:00 AM", "250", "743", 
"99.8", "58.4"), Columbia...16 = c("TEMP", "DegF", "-3", "1/31/2019 11:00 PM", 
"56", "1/24/2019 11:00 AM", "27", "744", "100", "10.6"), Columbia...17 = c("RH", 
"%", "26.2", "1/25/2019 5:00 PM", "91.9", "1/1/2019 5:00 AM", 
"60", "744", "100", "16.7"), Columbia...18 = c("BP", "in HG", 
"28.77", "1/20/2019 8:00 AM", "30.11", "1/22/2019 9:00 AM", "29.51", 
"744", "100", "0.2"), Columbia...19 = c("RAIN", "in", "0", "1/1/2019 1:00 AM", 
"0.386", "1/5/2019 10:00 AM", "3.351", "744", "100", "No Data"
), `Elizabeth Trailer...20` = c("WSPD", "mph", "0.7", "1/27/2019 1:00 AM", 
"20", "1/21/2019 7:00 AM", "5", "740", "99.4", "2.7"), `Elizabeth Trailer...21` = c("WDIR", 
"Deg", "34", "1/1/2019 1:00 AM", "330", "1/1/2019 1:00 AM", "228", 
"744", "100", "81.7"), `Elizabeth Trailer...22` = c("TEMP", "DegF", 
"2", "1/31/2019 3:00 AM", "58", "1/1/2019 8:00 AM", "32", "744", 
"100", "10.6"), `Elizabeth Trailer...23` = c("RH", "%", "24.7", 
"1/22/2019 3:00 PM", "89.7", "1/1/2019 3:00 AM", "52.3", "744", 
"100", "17.1"), `Elizabeth Trailer...24` = c("BP", "in HG", "29.2", 
"1/20/2019 10:00 AM", "30.63", "1/22/2019 9:00 AM", "30.03", 
"744", "100", "0.2"), `Elizabeth Trailer...25` = c("RAIN", "in", 
"0", "1/1/2019 2:00 AM", "0.222", "1/20/2019 12:00 AM", "2.812", 
"744", "100", "No Data"), Flemington...26 = c("BP", "in HG", 
"29.07", "1/20/2019 9:00 AM", "30.5", "1/22/2019 9:00 AM", "29.89", 
"743", "99.8", "0.2"), Flemington...27 = c("RH", "%", "26.7", 
"1/11/2019 2:00 PM", "92.7", "1/1/2019 3:00 AM", "59.9", "743", 
"99.8", "18.2"), Flemington...28 = c("SOLAR", "Langleys", "No Data", 
"1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", 
"0", "0", "No Data"), Flemington...29 = c("TEMP", "DegF", "0", 
"1/31/2019 6:00 AM", "59", "1/24/2019 10:00 AM", "29", "743", 
"99.8", "10.6"), Flemington...30 = c("WSPD", "mph", "0.6", "1/31/2019 9:00 PM", 
"12.3", "1/24/2019 9:00 AM", "3.7", "743", "99.8", "2.6"), Flemington...31 = c("WDIR", 
"Deg", "69", "1/5/2019 6:00 AM", "317", "1/6/2019 8:00 PM", "211", 
"743", "99.8", "63.6"), Flemington...32 = c("RAIN", "in", "0", 
"1/1/2019 2:00 AM", "0.234", "1/24/2019 1:00 PM", "2.775", "743", 
"99.8", "No Data"), `Fort Lee Near Road...33` = c("WSPD", "mph", 
"1.2", "1/15/2019 7:00 PM", "18", "1/21/2019 5:00 PM", "5.9", 
"744", "100", "3.2"), `Fort Lee Near Road...34` = c("WDIR", "Deg", 
"68", "1/13/2019 9:00 PM", "306", "1/20/2019 12:00 PM", "228", 
"744", "100", "65.6"), `Fort Lee Near Road...35` = c("TEMP", 
"DegF", "0", "1/31/2019 5:00 AM", "57", "1/1/2019 10:00 AM", 
"30", "744", "100", "10.3"), `Fort Lee Near Road...36` = c("RH", 
"%", "26.9", "1/25/2019 9:00 PM", "90.6", "1/1/2019 2:00 AM", 
"54.3", "744", "100", "17"), `Fort Lee Near Road...37` = c("BP", 
"in HG", "28.9", "1/20/2019 10:00 AM", "30.29", "1/22/2019 10:00 AM", 
"29.7", "744", "100", "0.2"), `Fort Lee Near Road...38` = c("RAIN", 
"in", "0", "1/1/2019 2:00 AM", "0.244", "1/24/2019 10:00 AM", 
"3.507", "744", "100", "No Data"), `Newark Firehouse...39` = c("BP", 
"in HG", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Newark Firehouse...40` = c("RH", 
"%", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Newark Firehouse...41` = c("SOLAR", 
"Langleys", "0", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "0.758", "1/25/2019 12:00 PM", 
"0.097", "744", "100", "0.1"), `Newark Firehouse...42` = c("TEMP", 
"DegF", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Newark Firehouse...43` = c("WSPD", 
"mph", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Newark Firehouse...44` = c("WDIR", 
"Deg", "No Data", "1/1/2019 1:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 1:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Newark Firehouse...45` = c("RAIN", 
"in", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Rider University...46` = c("RH", 
"%", "26", "1/11/2019 3:00 PM", "93.1", "1/1/2019 2:00 AM", "58.8", 
"737", "99", "17.9"), `Rider University...47` = c("TEMP", "DegF", 
"2", "1/31/2019 12:00 AM", "60", "1/1/2019 8:00 AM", "30", "737", 
"99", "10.9"), `Rider University...48` = c("WSPD", "mph", "0.3", 
"1/26/2019 7:00 PM", "17.1", "1/20/2019 5:00 PM", "4.5", "737", 
"99", "3.8"), `Rider University...49` = c("WDIR", "Deg", "104", 
"1/1/2019 1:00 AM", "333", "1/1/2019 1:00 AM", "244", "737", 
"99", "61.5"), `Rider University...50` = c("SOLAR", "Langleys", 
"No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Rider University...51` = c("BP", 
"in HG", "29.11", "1/20/2019 9:00 AM", "30.56", "1/22/2019 10:00 AM", 
"29.94", "737", "99", "0.2"), `Rider University...52` = c("RAIN", 
"in", "0", "1/1/2019 2:00 AM", "0.317", "1/19/2019 11:00 PM", 
"3.262", "737", "99", "No Data"), `Rutgers University...53` = c("BP", 
"in HG", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Rutgers University...54` = c("TEMP", 
"DegF", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Rutgers University...55` = c("RH", 
"%", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Rutgers University...56` = c("RAIN", 
"in", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data"), `Rutgers University...57` = c("SOLAR", 
"watts/m2", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", "No Data", "1/1/2019 12:00 AM", 
"No Data", "0", "0", "No Data")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**This is what I have tried so far but am stuck on how to go further:**

```
df2<-df%>%
  gather(Site,Value,2:57)%>% 
  mutate_if(str_detect(., 'Bayonne|Camden Spruce St|Columbia|Elizabeth Trailer|
                       Rider University|Rutgers University|Fort Lee Near Road|
                       Flemington|Newark Firehouse'), 
            ~str_replace_all(., c("Bayonne.*" = "Bayonne",
                                  "Camden Spruce St.*" = "Camden Spruce St",
                                  "Columbia.*" = "Columbia",
                                  "Elizabeth Trailer.*"="Elizabeth Trailer",
                                  "Rider University.*" = "Rider University",
                                  "Flemington.*" = "Flemington",
                                  "Fort Lee Near Road.*" = "Fort Lee Near Road",
                                  "Rutgers University.*" = "Rutgers University",
                                  "Newark Firehouse.*" = "Newark Firehouse")))
```

Comment: The Site column doesn't look like a regular data.frame row in expected output

Comment: @akrun yeah you are right. I'm not too worried about having that column look like that. It can have the site repeated for min,max,mean

Comment: one thing i observed that the data include only `Jan` data.

Comment: @akrun I only included Jan data to make it minimal. I can include it all if it's more helpful

Comment: it's  okay.  I was just reporting that I am not missing anything

Comment: I've been working on this for a bit, This definitely can be done quicker in excel. Its just a pivot table.

Comment: @PloniAlmoni Unfortunately, I don't have access to excel at the moment.

Comment: @akrun I updated the expected output with the parameters shown. Thanks.

Comment: What are those 'Annual' values column

Comment: @akrun it's the mean, min, and max for all 12 months